# Why does the voltage over a fuse increase even though there is no current

Tags: current, fuses, circuit-protection, voltage

I noticed during several fuse tests that when the current goes to zero (it might be that the fuse was melted down) the voltage drop over the fuse rises a certain period of time and drops down steep.
How do you explain this rise of voltage after the current flow goes to zero?
Are there any parasitic effects?
Power supply over fuse to a load, so quite a simple test build-up with 300A constant current until 83.33sec and then it goes down to zero, the shunt voltage during this period of time goes from 498.465mV @ 83.3sec to 939.504mV @ 112sec. The purpose of the test was a short circuit test.
elow are the measured values & test biuld-up as additional information.

[image: Current flow]
[image: shunt voltage]
[image: schematic]

Thank you in advance.
Oliver

Comment: That makes no sense. If a fuse is blown, the voltage drop across the fuse approaches its maximum value. What is your setup?

Comment: Power supply over fuse to a load, so quite a simple test build-up with 300A constant current until 83.33sec and then it goes down to zero, the shunt voltage during this period of time goes from 498.465mV @ 83.3sec to 939.504mV @ 112sec. The purpose of the test was a short circuit test. I thought the same that the fuse blows and afterwards the voltage slowly decreases to zero. Is it possible that the arcing or the silica inside the fuse plays a role ? Or might it be relevant that inside the fuse there are two current traces compareable to a Dual-element fuse ?

Comment: _”it might be that the fuse was melted down”_ Please find out before asking. A melted fuse’s job is to produce counter voltage to not allow current to flow. It may seems highly unintuitive until you look into HV breakers and disconnectors.

Comment: the fuse is blown but the measured values show the case I mentioned before. I added pictures to the original question.

Comment: Is it possible that the gap through melting was overbridged and the voltage again was back in the circuit with an arc continually failing and reforming and building up voltage peaks ? It is quite a crude theory but what do you think ? Or did I misinterpret something ?

Comment: Please draw a schematic of your measurement setup.

Comment: I added a schematic. Thank you for your interest & help.

Comment: Is it possible, that your voltage measurement system went into range error condition after the fuse is blown and produces the value zero in this situation?

Comment: Is your voltage probe able to survive the maximum voltage of your current driver? That drop to zero looks ominous.

Comment: Those two plots look like they're not aligned in time, could you please upload a set of consistent captures

Comment: Your "schematic" looks vaguely like a Simulink diagram; is this all simulated?